# Can't use sysAuxClkRateSet( int ticksPerSecond ) in VxWorks RTP application

Tags: c++, vxworks, rtos, wind-river-workbench

I am able to use the aux clock API's from Kernel Image project, but when tried to use the same API's for example sysAuxClkRateSet( int ticksPerSecond ) in the RTP Project, i am getting undefined reference to the sysAuxClkRateSet error. I'm working on Vxworks 7.0. I added the API to the custom system call list and tried it, the compiler errors are getting resolved, but when the control hits that API, it is failing to work and the board is rebooting. I'm using TI Sitara a9, 4377 board. Any inputs on how to get it worked would really help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Did you add the required components in the Image project?

Comment: RTP(user space) does not have the same privilege as DKM(kernel space).      
                                                                                            Another possibility is sysAuxClkRate is limited in kernel configuration

Comment: @Harry: Image Project? Image project it is working fine, problem is with the RTP. Yeah when i tried it with Image project, i added all the required components to the configuration.

Comment: @endTunnel: yeah i realise that it is limited to kernel configuration, but documents say the calls can be done either by using Public message queues/Custom system calls etc.. any idea on how to use them to get it working in RTP?

Comment: Even if you give values greater than kernel config limits, your board should not reboot, so the problem seems to be somewhere else. Can you try a small program in DKM to set and get sysAuxClkRate and check if it is working there?

Comment: @endTunnel: you are right, the board is now not rebooting. But the intention is to use the Kernel API in User Space, is it possible? if so may i know how?

Comment: You may create a message queue to communicate between RTP and kernel. RTP can send a message, which upon reception by kernel will call the appropriate function of your choice.  There may be better ways, but this is one that comes to my mind at the moment

Comment: @endTunnel: Thanks that's an interesting solution.  I'll have to give it a try. I found information to do this using custom system call mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysAuxClkRateSet is a Kernel Space API, and is not present in the user mode header files.

In order to use this functionality from an RTP you can either use a mechanism such as a msgQ, to send commands from an RTP to a kernel space task, or write a custom system call to expose this function.

For this particular use case, you would probably want to create a static system call, which means you can call sysAuxClkRateSet directly from the RTP. This would require modifications to, and rebuild of, the VxWorks libraries, so you will probably want to base your kernel on a VSB project rather than the default libraries - although if you are using VxWorks 7 you will already have a VSB.

Comment: Thanks for the information!! Anyway i already implemented it using static custom system call, but i wanna know how i can implement the same using msgQ. Could you please elaborate a little more about this method?

Comment: @Sukum The basic idea is that you have a task in the kernel reading a msgQ. When it gets a message , it calls sysAuxClkRateSet. Your RTP sends a msg via the a, probably containing the value you want to set. You can extend this to handle an arbitrary number of commands, and could use a second q to send responses if needed.

Comment: But that is overkill for this purpose, and a static system call is the best approach here.

Comment: Please consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it is useful

Answer (score 0):

sysAuxClkRateSet is kernel space API hence will not work in RTP.